# ReadyRoll Project: Migration ID Duplicate

Tags: visual-studio, redgate

The Migration ID in this script file duplicates that of another migration. To assign a unique ID to the migration, open the file in Visual Studio, remove the Migration tag, save and click 'Insert Metadata'.

I am trying to build a readyroll project, but i got this error. I am unable to see the 'Insert Metadata' option in VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see a button to insert metadata if you open the script and remove the first line of the file (which begins with `-- <Migration`) and save the script:

[image]

If the button does not appear, then you can manually replace the migration metadata with a new unique ID, for example:

`-- <Migration ID="af207303-9c4f-4543-8303-704b5f4beaf1" />
GO
PRINT 'Hello world';
GO`

The project should build successfully after making these changes.

Comment: After changing the Migration ID, can I run the scripts again keeping the shadow database or should i first remove the shadow database?

Comment: The shadow database should automatically rebuild itself if needed (e,g, the next time changes are imported), so it shouldn't be necessary to remove it.

Comment: The Script Status of the scripts is 'Imported'. I checked semantic versioning for this project and got errors. I wanted to undo these changes and build the project again. Since the scripts are already imported, will it make any difference ?

Comment: I get this error when i open the log 'An item with the same key has already been added.'

Comment: Can I run the same migration script(with no changes in the script or the target DB) after changing the Migration ID and without deleting the shadow database?

Comment: If you delete the appropriate record from the [__MigrationLog] table in your target database, that will cause the script to be re-executed the next time you deploy your ReadyRoll project. The shadow db will not be affected.

Comment: I'm trying to build a readyroll project from teamcity & it gives me 2 errors, E:\\\\Project\Migrations\1.0.0\0001_20161019-1453_DS.sql The Migration ID in this script file (Migrations\1.0.0\0001_20161019-1453_DS.sql) duplicates that of another migration (Migrations\0001_20161019-1453_DS.sql). To assign a unique ID to the migration, open the file in VS, remove the <Migration /> tag, save and click 'Insert Metadata'. 'This script is excluded from the project. Please either remove the file from disk or add it into the project.' I am new to databases and readyroll, if I can get any support .

Comment: Ah it looks like the file "0001_20161019-1453_DS.sql" was copied when SemVer was enabled (whereas it should have been moved to the 1.0.0 folder). Try deleting the following file from source control and it should build: Migrations\0001_20161019-1453_DS.sql

Comment: I build the project before checking SemVer. All this happened after I checked SemVer option in project settings and created a folder 1.0.0 --> copied files from root to that folder. Currently, I have unchecked SemVer option and excluded the folder 1.0.0 and the 2 files that i copied. It's still showing me that error.

Comment: The files need to be physically removed from the folder, not just the project. If you use windows explorer, do you still see any files in the folders?

Comment: I am able to see the files in the folder on the server(TFS).

Comment: Ok great, let me know if the error persists after the duplicates have been removed from TFS